# Wordpress on Cpanel/WHM without DNS

Tags: wordpress, cpanel, whm

Anyone have experience setting up different environments for WP?

Currently we have to setup local, dev, staging environments for WP. Unfortunately we don't have a DNS. We have WHM/CPanel setup and I'm currently accessing the subdomain ('dev') by using ip/~username/dev.

I found [this documentation](http://abandon.ie/notebook/wordpress-configuration-for-multiple-environments) on setting up multiple environments, but it implies having a DNS for the staging environments. I actually have WP installed on the dev environment, but it wasn't styled - so the web root isn't reading properly, and I'm having issues connecting to the database.

If anyone knows what I would need to change the database settings to that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I figured this out. Because the SERVER_NAME is an ip address, it wasn't finding the "dev" in the url. I ended up using 'SCRIPT_FILENAME' instead.